# TCP Client Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've been trying to get flash to receive TCP messages from a small Serial to IP converter I have. Using some other software I can see the messages coming through so I know that bit it working.
From flash I've tried using a Socket and an XML socket but I'm not really sure what I'm doing, I've managed to get a connection but it doesn't seem to output the data, or trigger events when data is received.
Not sure I'm going the right way about this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is your server running online or locally? If it's online, let me know the URI and the port and I'll post a snippet, just wrote a simple TCP client the other day so shouldn't be that big a deal to write a snippet for you.

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=69) on the basics of the Binary Socket.  This example is for a pop server, but the concept is similar.

Comment: It's running locally, it's just one of these: http://tibbo.com/products/controllers/ds203.html running in TCP mode. I'll just read through that tutorial and the article posted bellow and let everyone know if it sorts it out. Thanks!

Comment: The binary socket is working! Thanks so much, getting some unrecognised data trailing it but I can get rid of that easy enough. I'm fairly new to this site and don't appear to be able to tick yours as the answer, maybe because it's a comment. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: You should write up your solution as an answer and then mark it as the solution.  That way future StackOverflow visitors have clear documentation as to your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is the code I used to get this working. Thanks for the help guys.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.net.Socket;

var RFIDSocket:Socket = new Socket(RFIDSocketIP,RFIDSocketPort);

RFIDSocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketData);

private function socketData(e:ProgressEvent):void {
        var rawData:String = RFIDSocket.readUTFBytes(RFIDSocket.bytesAvailable);
        var RFIDData:String = RFIDData.substring(1,11);
        if(debugMode){
            MonsterDebugger.trace(this, RFIDData);
        }
        RFIDSocket.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are probably hitting security restrictions. Flash needs permission to connect to any server through a socket, it looks for permission on port 843. [Adobe has a pretty good document on the restrictions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html), as well as some sample code for getting around it. If you don't have direct access over the server you are trying to connect to, you may need to explore using a proxy server.